# how can i write a method to check characters whether it matches the input argument?

Tags: oop

I want to write a boolean function call isDistrict (String districtCheck) {}
and i need to use this method for checking district is the same as disrictCheck, if yes it will return turn and the other will return flase.but i hv no ideal to do this.

```
 public boolean isDistrict (String districtCheck) {
      // TODO: Missing logic. Help
 }
```

For example if I would have this String, where I would like to check for Kwun Tong:
address:Room A,32/F,456 XXX,Kwun Tong,Kowloon
districtCheck:Kwun Tong true
When I would check for Hung Hom, I would get:
districtCheck:Hung Hom false

Comment: Just look for `indexOf` and if the index is higher then -1, then you have found the district.

Comment: Why don't you just Google something like "java check if string is in another string"? -1 for no research effort

Comment: Just research on Java String manipulation methods. That way you will learn more.

Comment: i'm sorry for that but i hv no ideal to do that
i just know i can use the split or tokenizer  to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
 String address = "Room A,32/F,456 XXX,Kwun Tong,Kowloon"

 ...

 public boolean isDistrict (String districtCheck){
     return address.contains(districtCheck)
 }
```